# Why is there no text showing up on my screen?

Tags: python, pygame

No text is showing up on my screen when this is ran, I've tried diffrent methods and everything. My images are loading before the text, and there is an update function

```
global font
global S
Seconds = 5
Black = (0,0,0)
White = (255,255,255)
#Story Text
Story = []
Story.append("You're Going To Try And Turn It Into a Trading Hub.")    
Story.append("There Isn't Anyone There, It's Yours Now.")
Story.append('You Go In Hoping For No One To Be There.')
Story.append('You Stumble Upon a Vacant Trading Station.')

#Display Story Text
if S > -1:
    startingtext = font.render(Story[S], True, White)
    startingtextRect = startingtext.get_rect()
    startingtextRect.center = (137 // 2, 78 // 3)
    window.blit(startingtext, startingtextRect) 
    if S > 0:
        if Wait == (Seconds * 1):
            S = 2
        elif Wait == (Seconds * 2):
            S = 1
        elif Wait == (Seconds * 3):
            S = 0
        elif Wait == (Seconds * 4):
            S = -1
```

S equals 3 by the way, and the font does work.

Comment: Please include a minimal executable program so that the community can analyze the program and provide suggestions.

Comment: @NoDakker How do i do that?

Comment: At the very least, include the other portions of your program so that the community can copy/paste it and run it to analyze your issue.

Comment: You can read [mre] or [ask]. You might also find taking the [tour] beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

The Game Loop was:

```
Image()
Update()
Text()
```

Update need to be last

Comment: @TomServo this implies that the answer was placing the `Text()` function before the `Update()` function, the latter causes a screen redraw. In the original order, only the image is shown, the text is never updated to the screen and is then overwritten by the next call to `Image()`.